# IndexOf function is always returing -1

Tags: javascript

I am using indexOf function to check whether specific string exist in the given array or not but It is giving me "-1" always even though specific string exist in given array. Below is code for same.

```
var independentLocations = ['/home', '/login','/ImpersonateUser'];
independentLocations.indexOf("/Authorization/ImpersonateUser");
```

Above code giving result "-1" each time even though "ImpersonateUser" is available in given array.

Please help me in this.

Comment: The array does not contain the string `"/Authorization/ImpersonateUser"`

Comment: Read the DOCS: [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)  *"...returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array"*

Comment: You array doesn't have the value you looking for. Index starts from 0 and if it can not find any corresponding value, it returns -1.

Comment: Is there any way to check specific characters or string exist in the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) in combination with:

[String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (bug-prone solution) :

```js
const independentLocations = ['/home', '/login','/ImpersonateUser'];
const path = "/Authorization/ImpersonateUser";

const idx = independentLocations.findIndex(x => path.includes(x));

console.log(idx); // 2
```

**Notice:** that's the simplest but might be bug-prone: for example, if you use i.e: `"/Authorization/ImpersonateUsers"` (notice the `"s"`) it will still retun a matching index.

to make it more precise you might use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```js
const independentLocations = ['/home', '/login','/ImpersonateUser'];
const path = "/Authorization/ImpersonateUser";

const idx = independentLocations.findIndex(x => new RegExp(`\\b${x}\\b`).test(path));

console.log(idx); // 2
```

Comment: @PrajapatiVikas you're welcome. I've edited the answer with an important NOTICE. Make sure to read it.

Comment: Yes updated answer is more precise. Thanks again